# Память в Java

Tags: java

Верно ли: “Переменные, объявленные в методе - лежат на стеке, а объявленные в классе попадают в кучу”?

Comment: Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, литературу на эту тему.

Comment: зачем тебе все это? гугли... http://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Comment: Зачем тебе знать что в куче, а что в стеке?

Comment: Расположение данных напрямую влияет на скорость работы всего приложения особенно в больших масштабах. Поэтому мне бы хотелось решать проблемы производительности продуманным кодом (насколько это возможно), а не покупкой дорогостоящего железа

Comment: Java идеологи думают по другому:) им проще докупить железа.
Но когда у них случается коллапс, приходят старые с\с++ программисты, которые дописывают код как нужно и оттягивают коллапс жава-кода (не жавы, а какого то конкретного кода) на какое-то кол-во лет:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Верно, но не совсем. Переменные метода примитивного типа скорее всего будут лежать в стеке.
А вот непримитивного типа - тут чуточку сложнее. Сама ссылка будет лежать в стеке (4-8 байт, в зависимости от реализации), а вот сам объект - в куче.

Но не нужно забывать, что это все детали реализации. Представим себе виртуальную машину на каком то сферическом процессоре, где нет стека, а только куча. Конечно, можно иммитировать, но ...
С другой стороны, можно написать так, что бы не использовать стек для хранения переменных (вопрос эффективности оставим в стороне).

Поэтому, правильным ответом будет - зависит от реализации виртуальной машины.